# How to get list of nested groups within an AD group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

In PowerShell script, I need to get all nested group within a group. The output could be an array of group names (doesn't need any level or members).

I googled some AD scripts but they include members. The Get-ADGroupMember method also has size result error with thousand of users.

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried so far along with the specific issues/errors you are getting.

Comment: Here is the error```Get-ADGroupMember : The size limit for this request was exceeded
At line:1 char:12
+ $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select -ExpandPropert ...```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom function to do this:

```
Function Get-ADNestedGroups {
    param($Members)

    foreach ($member in $Members) {
        $out = Get-ADGroup -filter "DistinguishedName -eq '$member'" -properties members
        $out | Select-Object Name
        Get-ADNestedGroups -Members $out.Members
    }
}

$group = "Group Name"
$members = (Get-ADGroup -Identity $group -Properties Members).Members
Get-ADNestedGroups $members
```

Just provide your starting or top level group name in the `$group` variable. Then just execute the code. This will rely on the `Members` property results from the `Get-ADGroup` command and recursively pipe those members into `Get-ADGroup`. This is configured to only output the `Name` property of each found group.

**Disclaimer:** This code is not efficient. It can become more efficient with more information about your directory structure, naming conventions, etc. The problem is not knowing the difference between a user and a group without querying that object. If all groups were in a higher level OU called groups, then we could filter out anything not a child of that container and then only look up the resulting objects.

Comment: The script will be run in variant AD servers of our clients so I'm not sure about their directory structures. Based on your script, I'm trying to narrow the members to be group only in the Get-ADGroup method. For example with a filter 'objectClass'="Group" but not luck. Please advice if you have any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: @PhucNguyen Pease doesn't add further requirements after the fact. All this information should have been included in your original question. Please update it to include this or open a new call if you have a different question :)